# angular4 component css appends random string with background image name

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-components

I'm working with Angular4. The Problem is that I've written some css in my-component.css file and have attached a background image to a div using following css code snippet.

```
.bg {
  background-image: url("../../../../Resources/images/my-image.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

But problem is that I can't see the background image. Reason what I found is that I can see background-image of that div as following in browser while inspecting elements.

```
background-image: url(my-image.b907916d510a47210902.jpg)
```

Not able to understand why the browser is appending extra string with image name. This newly appended string keeps on changing when I reload page.

Comment: How are you compiling your project?

Comment: using : ng serve

Comment: Can you share with me your styles and image location path ??

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

```
 background-image: url("./Resources/images/my-image.jpg");
```

Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: it isn't correct path of my image. I've added correct path in my question

Comment: can you share your file structure?